# Bash/Shell How to remove extra spaces in a variable?

Tags: string, bash

How to remove extra spaces in a variable?

```
VAR="    Eget ac vel volutpat      dic  tumst   est dui      adipiscing  "

Correct result: VAR="Eget ac vel volutpat dic tumst est dui adipiscing"
```

There are over 16,000,000 to be edited; `sed` is too slow!

!!! E D I T !!!

String OK! Thank you all

BUT

Text in array problem, gaps remain :-(

```
ITM=("  Eget ac  vel volutpat   |  Vel volutpat     dic tumst "
     "    Vestibulum  laoreet     a semper  |orttitor      eu laoreet justo congue ")

IFS=$'|'

for (( i=0 ; i<16000000 ; i++ ))
do
    AAA=( ITM[$i] )
    B=${AAA[0]}     # "  Eget ac  vel volutpat   "
    C=${AAA[1]}     # "  Vel volutpat     dic tumst "

done
```

Comment: 16 million shell variables?  _You're doing it wrong!_

Comment: I very much doubt that pushing all 16 million lines at once through sed will be that slow compared to anything you script in bash.

Comment: @bitmask: it depends on whether he's processing all 16 million lines through a single instance of sed (fast) or running sed 16 million times (once per array element) (very slow). It all depends on where those 16 million elements are coming from; if they're coming a file, I'd run it through sed first, then process that output a line at a time (and for God's sake and *don't* put it in an array unless you really need to).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Yes, that was what I meant. Use one `sed` instance and have it process all lines, each holding one of the strings.

Comment: @bitmask: Now that I reread it, that was actually explicit in your original comment. But I suspect that's not what Charlie was doing...

Comment: nobody knows the solution? :-(

Comment: I had the same problem, and indeed the first way to avoid losing a lot of speed, is to call sed only once, instead of calling it on each line/variable

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to spawn subshells for this.  Just use bash's built-in pattern substitution.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ shopt -s extglob
[ghoti@pc ~]$ VAR="    Eget ac vel volutpat      dic  tumst   est dui      adipiscing  "
[ghoti@pc ~]$ VAR=${VAR//+( )/ }
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "$VAR"
 Eget ac vel volutpat dic tumst est dui adipiscing 
[ghoti@pc ~]$ VAR=${VAR#+( )}
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "$VAR"
Eget ac vel volutpat dic tumst est dui adipiscing
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Comment: That reduces the spaces but does not collapse them.

Comment: It replaces `+( )` (any number of spaces) with a single space.  What do you mean by "collapse"?

Comment: Am I just seeing things?  I meant this for a post that suggested ${VAR//  / }.  That post was apparently deleted.  Objection retracted.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes, ex :

```
$ VAR="    Eget ac vel volutpat      dic  tumst   est dui      adipiscing  "     
$ echo $VAR
Eget ac vel volutpat dic tumst est dui adipiscing
$ echo "$VAR"
    Eget ac vel volutpat      dic  tumst   est dui      adipiscing  
$
```

If you prefer :

```
$ VAR="    Eget ac vel volutpat      dic  tumst   est dui      adipiscing  "
$ VAR="$(echo $VAR)"
$ echo "$VAR"
Eget ac vel volutpat dic tumst est dui adipiscing
```

This behaviour is called *word splitting*.

**NOTE**

as mentioned in the comments, you should use this only if you know that your variables contains no special characters like `*`.

Comment: sputnick: thank, you but I do not want to write, I need to have it in a variable ...

Comment: @Lev Levitsky : `x=$(</usr/share/dict/british); echo $x > /dev/null` : no errors. Try it, you will see.

Comment: An alternative to command subsitition: `arr=( $VAR ); VAR="${arr[*]}"`

Comment: Removing the quotes is dangerous. There might be any other sort of funny character in the string that will be expanded.

Comment: And what happens when `VAR="echo *"` ?  If the OP provides a dangerous example, it's better to show him a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Shell is not really set up to do massive data processing, even processing as simple as collapsing spaces.  But here is a solution without using `sed`

```
VAR="    Eget ac vel volutpat      dic  tumst   est dui      adipiscing  "
VAR=$(echo $VAR)
```

This code will set VAR to the collapsed version of the original var.  You can see this by executing:

```
echo "$VAR"
```

result:

```
Eget ac vel volutpat dic tumst est dui adipiscing
```

Comment: You edited your post to include that.  Your minus 1 on my answer is unnecessary.

Comment: =) Don't be paranoid, it's not me. Moreover, "edited 22 mins ago" while you have answered 13 mins ago...